# Two pf-statuses with the same function code and different descriptions?

Tags: abap, dynpro

I have a simple problem and I wonder how to solve it. I already searched online but probably dont know the right key words to find the solution in the internet. I am sure, that somebody else have had this issue before me :)

I have a program with e.g. two dynpros. Each dynpro has an own pf-status. Now I want both pf-status to have a button with the function code "CONFIRM", but with a different function text or description or icon.
This seems to be impossible by now, as if I change the description or icon in the one status, it also changes in the other one.

Is it possible to handle the same function code in 2 different pf-status within one program with two different descriptions or icons?

I will change the function codes if I dont find the answer. But I really want to know!

Many thanks in advance

Comment: In the pf-status double-click the function code ("CONFIRM"), a pop-up comes up, here you can change the text to dynamic. You have to link a field (from the program), if you click F1 (Help) in the field, another popup comes up, which explains exactly what you have to do.

Comment: Thank you very much József, I will try this!

Comment: It may be a little bit weird for the user to see 2 buttons with different texts but which do exactly the same thing. Anyway, I don't think it costs anything to use two function code names.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right. I was just interested if it works at all.